# Can't push to org cause of this error can someone please take a look

Tags: lightning-web-components

ERROR running force:source:push:  Unexpected file found in package directory: /Users/muhaimennoor/lwc session/lwcNew/force-app/main/default/aura/meetingRoom/meetingRoomAura.auradoc

Answer (score 3):

I would say that your problem is that in

```
/Users/muhaimennoor/lwc session/lwcNew/force-app/main/default/aura/meetingRoom/
```

you have the file

```
meetingRoom/meetingRoomAura.auradoc
```

but it should actually be

```
meetingRoom/meetingRoom.auradoc
```

Rename the file and try to push it again ;)

Comment: Thanks I got it to work.